# C# XNA Draw blips when alien is detected

Tags: c#, xna, generic-collections

I'm sure this has a very simple solution but I'm just not sure how to go about it. In fact I don't even know where to start.

I'm attempting to make a really basic game where several (local)players walk around a single screen level with detection devices to detect aliens through walls.

When a player has turned on their detector any aliens within range are to be highlighted by a blip or rectangle outline.The blip will follow the moving alien.

Each player has their own color blip, so that they can see who is detecting which alien. So multiple blips can exist on the same alien.

Currently I have a player object, an alien object, and a blip object.

What's the best way to combine them so that multiple blips can exist on one alien?

I've tried doing something like:

```
if (detector.Active)
{
    for (int i = Alien.aliensList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                        new Blip(blipTexture, Alien.aliensList[i]);             
            }
}
```

But all this does is add a blip 60 times a seconds. So how can I tell the game that the alien already has one of my blips on it, but not care if there is one from another player?

Thanks :)

Comment: What does new blip(blipTexture, alien); actually do? You are not setting it to an object...

Comment: oops I left a bit out. Creating a new Blip object takes in an alien object, so that the blip knows where to appear, and who to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to an Alien into a Blip class. In Update method you will need to remove blink for killed enemies or enemeies that out from radar radius and add new blinks for new aliens. Having a link you can easily avoid duplication.

Also you can use a Dictionary  to hold all aliens. 
In this case, add AlienKey field for the Blip. I think this method is more preferable because every object receives its own unique key and eliminated the problem of waste in a heap departure aliens ;)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about dictionaries I will give that a try :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I ended up doing what I needed to by using two sets of lists for each player:
-aliensInRangeList 
-aliensIveTargetedList

When an alien comes with in range of a player , it gets added to the aliensInRangeList and then that list checks if that alien also exists in the aliensIveTargetedList.

If the alien exists in aliensInRangeList but not in aliensIveTargetedList, a blip is drawn on the alien, by that player. If the alien exists in both lists, no blips are drawn.

So this way it will not draw multiple blips from the same player, but it will draw a blip from each and every player.